# Odoo JSONRPC service (http.route type=json) not work

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, json-rpc

I'm trying create jsonrpc service in odoo. When I created clean module using doc https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/website.html and added such code

```
**[controllers.py]**
@http.route(['/my_academy/ret/'], type='json', auth="public")
    def change_size(self):
        return {'x': 1, 'y': 2}
```

try to connect from js:

```
    "use strict";
    var requestUrl = '/my_academy/ret/';

    openerp.jsonRpc(requestUrl, 'call', {})
        .then(function (data) {
            alert(data['x']);
        });
```

All work fine. I receive message '1'.
When i created module using doc https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html and added such code

```
**[controllers.py]**
@http.route(['/academy/jsonrpc/'], type='json', auth="public")
    def return_map(self):
        return {'x': 12345, 'y': 2222}
```

Modify js and try to connect

```
    "use strict";
    var requestUrl = '/academy/jsonrpc/';

    openerp.jsonRpc(requestUrl, 'call', {})
        .then(function (data) {
            alert(data['x']);
        });
```

I receive error

```
code: 200
data: Object
    arguments: Array[0]
        length: 0
        __proto__: Array[0]
        ....
    debug: "Traceback (most recent call last):↵  
            File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 539, in _handle_exception↵    
            return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)↵
            File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 152, in _dispatch↵    
            rule, arguments = self._find_handler(return_rule=True)↵  
            File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 65, in _find_handler↵    
            return self.routing_map().bind_to_environ(request.httprequest.environ).match(return_rule=return_rule)↵  
            File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1430, in match↵    
            raise NotFound()↵
            NotFound: 404: Not Found↵"
    message: ""
    name: "werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound"
    __proto__: Object

message: "Odoo Server Error"
__proto__:Object
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I use similar code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
@http.route(['/academy/jsonrpc'], type='json', auth="public", website=True)
def return_map(self, **post):
    return {'x': 12345, 'y': 2222}
```

it may help in your case.

Comment: have you imported your controller in init.py

Comment: I tried to use auth="none" - nothing. If module develop for website then all work fine. If module develop for backend  such as https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html i have problem. May be I need declared any modules or secure parameters?

Comment: Yes, I have.
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import controllers
import models
#interhits
from . import partner

Comment: this is code work fine
    @http.route('/academy/academy/', auth='public', website=True)
    def index(self, **kw):
        return http.request.render('academy.index', {
            'message': ["Hello World", "Hi all!"]
        })

Comment: but this is not Json :(

Comment: I don't know what help me. I try add data from controller.py to ir.model.access.csv, change parametrs @http.route, rename class, etc. Nothing! After that i change class declare from class Academy(http.Controller) to class Academy(openerp.http.Controller)/ I received error. Browser return 500. I could not remove/update module wuth this error.
I re-ran odoo server with parametr -u moduleName:
./odoo --addons-path=addons,my-modules -u academy . After that all work fine!